# How to equate cookware heat capacity: Thermal properties, maintaining temperature, break even point specific heat and conductivity

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

Thermal properties, maintaining temperature, break even point specific heat and conductivity:

I am thinking about a problem regarding cookware.  If a material has a high enough thermal conductivity, would it no longer be necessary for it to have high heat capacity in order for the temperature in the pan not to crash when adding, for example, cold proteins for high temperature searing?

Copper, for example, has a much higher thermal conductivity than cast iron, and, as a volumetric measure, per millimeter of pan thickness, similar, if not slightly less, heat capacity.  cast iron, however, can be made in greater thicknesses, increasing a pan’s heat capacity. A 5 mm cast iron skillet will have much more heat capacity than a 2 mm copper skillet, and will also be far less responsive in terms of heat transfer because of a far lower thermal conductivity, as well as the additional mass.

I am wondering to what extent the higher conductivity of copper overcomes this delta in heat capacity, because, although the thinner copper pan will store less heat, it will also uptake heat from the heat source far more rapidly, more quickly replenishing heat lost to the food.

how would I calculate The thermal conductivity required for one material to have the same heat capacity (not intrinsically, but functionally speaking, in terms of heat output per unit time into the food, without temperature crashing, ie to have the same ability to maintain temperature with a standardized heat source when a standardized mass of a certain food is added) as another, knowing the specific heat and thickness of each material?  How would I calculate, for example, how many millimeters of copper would be needed to match this functional “heat capacity” or stable heat output of 5 mm of cast-iron? or, what the thermal conductivity of 2 mm of material would have to be  to match the 5 mm of cast-iron.

To phrase the question another way, could an extremely thin piece of material (or, put differently, a material with virtually no heat capacity) match the heat output of the cast-iron skillet When challenged with cold food if it had an extraordinarily high thermal conductivity?

perhaps this is a function in someway of thermal diffusivity?

Comment: If you have a spare $3870, you can get one of these: https://shop.soy.com.tr/products/soy-gnt-series-pure-solid-silver-frying-pans. ;-)

Comment: With infinite heat capacity the temperature would not change when you drop cold food in

Comment: You want to drop food in and not have the pan surface temperature in contact with the food change much, even at short times, correct?

Comment: re: ed, I know soy turkiye!  absolutely gorgeous, they are on my list!  yes, I would love one of those.  Doesn’t answer my question though.

Comment: re: jon, thanks, but my question is about infinite conductivity, not heat capacity. Would infinite conductivity mimic infinite heat capacity?

Comment: re: chet, yes.  I am asking if very high thermal conductivity will equate, in this scenario, to high heat capacity.

Comment: Does anyone know if you can reply to individual posts? I’m new here, and using this on my phone.